# SQLITE TABLE Create error

Tags: javascript, sql, database, node.js, sqlite

I'm working off of an example to learn node.js/sqlite3, shown here: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/blob/master/examples/simple-chaining.js

In the example, the table only has only column, and I wanted to extend it so the table has three columns--for username, password, and login count.

So I changed the original code, here:

```
function createTable() {
    console.log("createTable lorem");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lorem (info TEXT)", insertRows);
}
```

to this:

```
function createTable() {
    console.log("createTable lorem");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lorem (info TEXT, name TEXT)", insertRows);
}
```

but when trying to fill it with values, I get an error:

```
~:dev$ node chaining.js 
createDb chain
createTable lorem
insertRows Ipsum i

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table lorem has 1 columns but 2 values were supplied
~:dev$
```

Am I creating the table incorrectly? I referred to the SQLITE api, as well as W3schools, but none seem to indicate that I'm doing it incorrectly.

I've provided my code below:

```
/**
 * Shows how to use chaining rather than the `serialize` method.
 */
"use strict";

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db;

function createDb() {
    console.log("createDb chain");
    db = new sqlite3.Database('chain.sqlite3', createTable);
}


function createTable() {
    console.log("createTable lorem");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT, name TEXT)", insertRows);
}

function insertRows() {
    console.log("insertRows Ipsum i");
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?, ?)");

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run("Ipsum " + i, "lala " + i);
    }

    stmt.finalize(readAllRows);
}

function readAllRows() {
    console.log("readAllRows lorem");
    db.all("SELECT rowid AS id, info, name FROM lorem", function(err, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info + ": " + row.name);
        });
        closeDb();
    });
}

function closeDb() {
    console.log("closeDb");
    db.close();
}

function runChainExample() {
    createDb();
}

runChainExample();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the table already exists, possibly from a previous run of your script. The quickest way to test this would be to just change the name of the sqlite database you are creating.

```
db = new sqlite3.Database('chain.sqlite3', createTable);
```

to

```
db = new sqlite3.Database('chain2.sqlite3', createTable);
```

If that works, then that's the issue. You could also modify your script to first DROP the table before creating it if it exists.